# Get text between two words in bash (multilines)

Tags: string, bash, text, get, between

i am fighting with this issue. I have this text:

```
Executables:   manatee-curl
Dependencies:  base ==4.*, manatee-core >=0.1.1, dbus-client ==0.3.*,
               stm >=2.1.2.0, containers >=0.3.0.0, gtk >=0.12.0,
               text >=0.7.1.0, mtl >=1.1.0.2, old-time -any,
               old-locale -any, glib >=0.12.0, gio >=0.12.0,
               filepath >=1.1.0.3, utf8-string >=0.3.4, bytestring -any,
               network -any, curl >=1.3.7, directory -any,
               template-haskell -any, derive -any, binary -any,
               regex-tdfa -any, dbus-core -any
Cached:        No
```

and i want to get all those words between "Dependencies:" and "Cached".
you can treat this text as a variable, for example:

echo $text | grep /dostuff/

To be clear, the output I want to get is:

```
base ==4.*, manatee-core >=0.1.1, dbus-client ==0.3.*,
stm >=2.1.2.0, containers >=0.3.0.0, gtk >=0.12.0,
text >=0.7.1.0, mtl >=1.1.0.2, old-time -any,
old-locale -any, glib >=0.12.0, gio >=0.12.0,
filepath >=1.1.0.3, utf8-string >=0.3.4, bytestring -any,
network -any, curl >=1.3.7, directory -any,
template-haskell -any, derive -any, binary -any,
regex-tdfa -any, dbus-core -any
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
echo "$text" | grep -Poz 'Dependencies:  \K(.*\n)*(?=Cached:)' | grep -Po '^ +\K.*'
```

Output:

```
base ==4.*, manatee-core >=0.1.1, dbus-client ==0.3.*,
stm >=2.1.2.0, containers >=0.3.0.0, gtk >=0.12.0,
text >=0.7.1.0, mtl >=1.1.0.2, old-time -any,
old-locale -any, glib >=0.12.0, gio >=0.12.0,
filepath >=1.1.0.3, utf8-string >=0.3.4, bytestring -any,
network -any, curl >=1.3.7, directory -any,
template-haskell -any, derive -any, binary -any,
regex-tdfa -any, dbus-core -any
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to get text between 2 patterns:

```
text=$(sed -n '/^Dependencies:/,/^Cached:/{$d;s/Dependencies: *//;p;}' file)

echo "$text"

base ==4.*, manatee-core >=0.1.1, dbus-client ==0.3.*,
               stm >=2.1.2.0, containers >=0.3.0.0, gtk >=0.12.0,
               text >=0.7.1.0, mtl >=1.1.0.2, old-time -any,
               old-locale -any, glib >=0.12.0, gio >=0.12.0,
               filepath >=1.1.0.3, utf8-string >=0.3.4, bytestring -any,
               network -any, curl >=1.3.7, directory -any,
               template-haskell -any, derive -any, binary -any,
               regex-tdfa -any, dbus-core -any
```

[IDEOne Working Demo](http://ideone.com/ZZ5Qwu)

Comment: Sorry but it's not working, when i try to output $text i just get nothing... :(

Comment: @ChristopherLoen please specify which `sed` ...  linux diff than default OSX for example

Comment: This was tested on OSX sed as well as on GNU sed

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^Dependencies:/{$1="";p=1} /^Cached:/{p=0} p{sub(/^ +/,"");print}' file

base ==4.*, manatee-core >=0.1.1, dbus-client ==0.3.*,
stm >=2.1.2.0, containers >=0.3.0.0, gtk >=0.12.0,
text >=0.7.1.0, mtl >=1.1.0.2, old-time -any,
old-locale -any, glib >=0.12.0, gio >=0.12.0,
filepath >=1.1.0.3, utf8-string >=0.3.4, bytestring -any,
network -any, curl >=1.3.7, directory -any,
template-haskell -any, derive -any, binary -any,
regex-tdfa -any, dbus-core -any
```

you can assign to a variable as usual

```
$ text=$(awk ...)
```